# What are the building blocks of digital circuit design in ICs?

Tags: digital-logic

I think that the building blocks of digital circuit design can be described as:

1. Counters
2. Finite State Machines
3. Memory blocks (use address to access data with read/write signals) and simple registers (use clock to store 1 bit)
4. Arithmetic and Logic operation blocks
5. Multiplexers/Demultiplexers

I think that all digital circuits can be broken down into these "functional" blocks. Ultimately Finite State Machines are made up of arithmetic & logic operations also and registers. Counters contain them as well. However, I think that is sufficiently low level of abstraction to describe complex digital circuits. Therefore, when a person starts learning digital circuit design and has grasped the concept of boolean algebra, logic gates, flip-flops and registers and they have to do their digital design, they should think it terms of this.

Another important aspect in hierarchical designs is, communication between different blocks. This could take form of simple handshake using read/valid signal or more complex interaction that is based on well defined data buses like Avalon, AMBA e.t.c.

I think that things like shift register and FIFO should be there in the list but am a bit confused.

Am I missing something here or got something wrong? Is there an agreed way to write down the list as a flat list or as a hierarchy? I think such a list can be help for new learners.

Comment: Lot of overlap in those classes since counters, ALUs and muxes are also finite state machines.

Comment: I don't really get where this list will take you because it differs greatly from circuit to circuit. As an aside, a Finite State Machines (FSM) is made up of state flip-flops and decision AND/OR/XOR/NOT gates. The latter decision gates convert a current state and inputs into a new state and outputs. They don't contain arithmetic circuits. People sometimes bury counters, buses and other circuitry into what they call an FSM but it's not then an FSM, only the control/decision part. I've seen FSMs as less important than your list suggests.

Comment: `Am I missing something here...` You're missing the fact that few topics can be classified in the way you're trying to classify 'digital circuit design'. Yes, many big designs contain a lot of counters, and ALUs, and suchlike. But if you build blocks as intermediate entities, then you can only make the designs that can be built out of those blocks. Like Darwin's 'Tree of Life' looks today more like a 'Web of Life', you'll always find new designs, and new species, that don't quite fit into the rules of inheritance that you're seeking. Chill, Aristotle is long dead.

Comment: `I think that all digital circuits can be broken down into these "functional" blocks` ... this cannot possibly be true, because you used the word `all` ... why are you stopping at `groups of logic gates` instead of going to individual logic gates? ... it is like a scientist saying that building blocks of matter are molecules, instead of saying that atoms are the building blocks

Comment: This kind of classification in the question is artificial. In System On Chips, a CPU is considered a functional block.

Comment: you can make a design out of a large box of NAND gates, if you want to overcomplicate it you can think and, or, not, or and, or, not, xor, nor, nand, and then go from there.  state machines and fifos and such are higher level concepts that are often implemented yes, but are they building blocks?  Sine there are so many ways to implement them with pros and cons they have their own sub categories.  when you get into what is actually on the chip it is the basics (and, or, not, etc various sizes), sram cells and a few other things depending on the cell library.

Comment: So I guess that there is no universally accepted abstracted building blocks of digital circuits. ok. I guess I shall have to delete this question.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7, this is a good question and it can be useful as a reference for future users.

Comment: The building blocks? transistors...